# What is wrong with my function that contains a "Attribute error"

Tags: python

Hey I'm getting this error on my code but I'm not sure why

my code for this function is:

```
def rotateImage90(image):
    ei = EmptyImage(image.getHeight(), image.getWidth())
    for i in range (image.getWidth()):
        for j in range(image.getHeight()):
            orginal = image.getPixel(i, j)
            ei.setPixel(image.getHeight() - j - 1, i, orginal)
    return ei
```

the error im getting is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#24>", line 1, in <module>
  drawImage("Spiderman", [spiderman, rotateImage90(spiderman)]) 
File "/Users/luisarroyo/Documents/project 7.py", line 52, in rotateImage90
  orginal = image.getPixel(i, j)   
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cImage.py", line 310, in getTkPixel
  p = [int(j) for j in self.im.get(x,y).split()] 
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Comment: `self.im.get(x,y)` returns a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) (which do not have split method).

Comment: @Mujeeb As you can see from the stack trace, the error originates in the module `cImage` that was not written by the OP.

Comment: @DYZ in the beginning of my program I added "from cImage Import *"

Comment: `import *` is the worst and most dangerous form of import. I suspect that some identifiers from `cImage` shadowed some `tk` identifiers. Replace `from cImage import *` with `import cImage`, use fully qualified names, and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Doesn’t solve your problem, but it seems like it would be a lot more efficient to get the image height and width outside the nested loops and then use those variables instead of querying for the height potentially thousands of times.